# SQL Query two tables and combine results (with a twist)

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables: `users` and `users_info`

`users` looks like this:

```
+----+----------+-------+
| id | slug     | name  |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 | theploki | Kris  |
+----+----------+-------+
```

and `users_info` looks like this:

```
+----+--------+----------+---------------+
| id | parent | info_key | info_val      |
+----+--------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | 1      | email    | kris@kris.com |
+----+--------+----------+---------------+
|  2 | 1      | age      | 28            |
+----+--------+----------+---------------+
```

I want to `SELECT` a `user` who has `user_info` email = 'kris@kris.com'
-  and -
return ALL `user_info` results that have a matching `users_info.parent = user.id`
-  and -
in a readable format (like `result['email'] = 'kris@kris.com'` and `result['id'] = 1` and `result['name'] = 'Kris'` and `result['age'] = 28`)

I'm sure this was answered in another question but I've been searching and reading answers that don't exactly work for me.

Obviously I make sure `info_key`s cannot match `users` column names.

I've tried INNER JOINs, OUTER JOINs, just plain JOINs and I've tried without any JOIN at all.

This doesn't work, but it kind of explains what I want to do:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE 1=1
AND users.slug='theploki'
AND (SELECT * FROM users_info
    WHERE users_info.parent = users.id
    AND 1=1
    AND users_info.info_key = 'email'
    AND users_info.info_val = 'kris@kris.com'
    GROUP BY users_info.parent)
GROUP BY users.id
```

Sometimes I won't be searching for an info column, and sometimes I won't be searching for a users column which is why I put `1=1`

Maybe it's just simpler to do two queries and combine them afterwards?

### UPDATE:

OK, here's the updated SQL query (provided by scaisEdge):

```
SELECT users.*, users_info.* FROM users
INNER JOIN users_info on users_info.parent = users.id
where users.id = (SELECT users_info.parent FROM users_info
    WHERE users_info.parent = users.id
    AND users_info.info_val = 'kris@kris.com')
```

This is very close, but returns a result set like this:

```
+----+----------+-------+----+--------+----------+---------------+
| id | slug     | name  | id | parent | info_key | info_val      |
+----+----------+-------+----+--------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | theploki | Kris  |  1 |  1     | email    | kris@kris.com |
+----+----------+-------+----+--------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | theploki | Kris  |  2 |  1     | age      | 28            |
+----+----------+-------+----+--------+----------+---------------+
```

but I want a result set like this:

```
+----+----------+-------+---------------+-----+
| id | slug     | name  | email         | age |
+----+----------+-------+---------------+-----+
|  1 | theploki | Kris  | kris@kris.com | 28  |
+----+----------+-------+---------------+-----+
```

Comment: What is the reason that you have information about users split into two tables like this? I can see if you want to have general key-value information pairs for users, but if the idea is that all or most users will have their ages and email tracked in the database, that should generally be part of the `users` table.

Comment: if you want to have all infos in one row from a customer we need all info_key(s) if there more than the 2 to build a pivot table

Comment: Basically I'm using this format for a few tables (like `Pages` and `Posts`) and some of them will have dynamic variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te user whit the same parent user should be

```
SELECT users.*, users_info.* FROM users
INNER JOIN users_info on users_info.parent_id = users.id
where users.id = (SELECT users_info.parent FROM users_info
    WHERE users_info.parent = users.id
    AND users_info.info_val = 'kris@kris.com')
```

just for sample  you can change user.* ord users_info.* with the column name and alias

```
SELECT users.slug,  users.name as name, group_concat(users_info.info_val) FROM users
INNER JOIN users_info on users_info.parent_id = users.id
where users.id = (SELECT users_info.parent FROM users_info
    WHERE users_info.parent = users.id
    AND users_info.info_val = 'kris@kris.com')
 group by users.name
```

Comment: This is great! But it only returns results from the `users` table. How can I also have it return all `users_info` results by the `info_key`?

Comment: This is great! Very close to what I want, but It's returning multiple rows of results because there are a few `info` matches. Is there a way to give each `info` result a variable?  I want every `users_info` result to be given an alias of its `info_key` so it returns only one row of the user's information.

Comment: That is helpful, but doesn't solve the problem. I've updated my question. If I do `users_info.info_val as email` then both `age` and `email` are put into an `email` column. I need the `info` columns to dynamically use the `info_key` as an alias.

Comment: You can use group_concat .. for getting al the info_val in one column .. otherwise  you must vwork on inner join whit the same table .. i have update the answer .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users_info.info_val AS email 
FROM users JOIN users_info  ON users_info.parent_id = users.id
WHERE users_info.info_key = 'email'
```

That should work for the result you want.  The other provided answer requires that you know the result you're looking for before you write the query. Still, as I mentioned in the comment above, this is an odd way to structure your database, and unless you have a specific reason, general user information like an email address would be in the `users` table.

If, however, your intent is to have a minimal table of users, and then generic key-value coded information for them, then this query will work.